# How to prevent simultaneous access to asp.net mvc action on same machine and different ones

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

So basically, I have a controller (SomeController.cs) method, call it Index(), and I want to prevent two simultaneous access to Index() locally and different machines since it involves heavy duty processing. Here is what my Controller methods looks like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.controllerObj = this;
    if(! _Ready)
    {
        lock(_Locker)
        {
            if(!_Ready)
            {
                 ViewBag.canStart = true;
                 _Ready = true;
             }

         }
     }
 }

public bool canStart(ViewDataDictionary vd)
{
    // Override the controller's ViewData dictionary with the one passed from the view.
    ViewData = vd;

    Setting settings = data.Settings.FirstOrDefault();

    if (settings == null)
    {
        settings = new Setting();
        data.Settings.Add(settings);
        data.SaveChanges();
    }

    var starter = new Guid();
    data.Entry(settings).Reload();

    if (settings.startedBy.HasValue && settings.startedBy != starter)
    {
        return false;
    }

    settings.startedBy = starter;
    ViewBag.Settings = settings;
    data.SaveChanges();

    return true;
}
```

Then I have following at the top of the file Index.aspx

```
var canStart = false;
if(ViewBag.canStart != null)
{
    canStart = (bool)ViewBag.controllerObj.canStart(ViewData);
}

if(canStart)
{
    // Heavy duty processing
}
```

So my question is when I navigate to Some/Index in two tabs of same browser, Index.aspx still gets access one after another. Why is the case? When I test in two different browsers, one browser will go ahead do the processing, another one will not.

UPDATE:

So I remove the lock and only use one private static variable shared within memory instead of double check lock. Also I check if the database table has been updated if two different machine are accessing at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this is really prone to errors (forever locked).

Comment: True, the private static _Ready seems to be shared across threads (two tabs of same browser), but not in two different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a vollation property to do this

```
private static volatile bool isExecuting = false;

public ActionResult Index()
{
   if(!isExecuting)
   {
      isExecuting = true;
      try
      {
          // Your instruction here.
      }
      finally
      {
         isExecuting = false;
      }          
   }
}
```

I think this may solve your problem.

Comment: I read about volatile keyword, but have not tried it out yet.